# global and local variable js

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, global-variables

i define a golbal variable:

```
var a;
```

and i have two functions in my code:

```
function n1 {a=0;}
function n2 {alert(a);}
```

i try to use value of a variable in first function in the other function but i get undefined variable error.
why i get undefined variable error?
i read about global and local scop but i confused about this problem.
also i tried this and get undefined error:

```
    function n1 {var a; a=0;}
    function n2 {alert(a);}
```

Comment: If you get an undefined variable error then the variable is not really global. Show a [mcve].

Comment: the way i see you first try, it should work. I suggest you post more code.

Answer (score -1):

Did you call function n1 before calling function n2??
Though the variable is declared globally, it does'nt hold any value and hence undefined.
The function n1() will initialize it and then the variable a will hold value 0. Then if you call function n2() , the alert dialog will display the value stored in variable a i.e. 0. 
Hence the value stored in the global variable is accessible in function n2().

[Attached the image of the code working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNTbB.png)